# How do you ensure that PyQt child widget is not larger than parent widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

When creating a small child widget I know how to get it to expand to the size of its parent widget, but if it is larger than its parent, it does not appear to shrink to the parent size. Example

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize

app = QApplication([])

window = QWidget()
window.setFixedSize(QSize(300,200))
window.show()

layout = QHBoxLayout()
window.setLayout(layout)

label = QLabel()
layout.addWidget(label)
print(label.size().width())

app.exec()
```

This prints 640, even though the parent is 300 wide. How can I correct this?

Comment: Well, one way would be add a check to see if the child's size exceeds the parent's size, in which case you set the child`s size to the parent`s size, otherwise you do not do anything special.

Comment: Thank you. I considered this, but then you also need to consider the parent margins and/or layout spacing. There's got to be a more elegant way?

Comment: Ok, I can verify that the problem occurs as described by OP. It does print `640` when window is clearly `300` px wide.

Comment: @bfris I was scratching my head about the problem, but yes the answers on that page explain exactly what is going on!

Comment: for this particular code if you add `app.processEvents()` just before your print statement, it seems to give you an accurate number. But in general, you have to use some trickery like connecting to the `resizeEvent` of `window`

Comment: @bpops Btw, how about using QT designer to create ui files than load the ui file. Since, designer can handle how to map full width label to the window, with many more properties to control to achieve what you want?

Comment: @bfris Yes! Explicitly setting the parent in the constructor solves the issue! That is very odd because you still have to call the addWidgget() function; seems redundant. Thank you

Comment: @akaAbdullahMateen I'm just a pyqt newbie and haven't played around with the designer yet.

Comment: @bfris after looking through this, this is my preferred solution. Just calling `app.processEvents()`

Comment: @bpops setting the parent in the constructor only changes the default behavior, which is to have a size of `100x30`, as explained in the other answer, *unless* the widget has explicitly set minimum/maximum sizes in its `__init__`. In any case, the printed value is completely irrelevant at that point, and you should *not* call `processEvents()` to get that: as long as there is a layout set, the widget will properly use as much space as it can, or eventually shrink if its size policy allows it and the parent has size restrictions like in your case.

Comment: @musicamante I think I got too excited about simply seeing a different size and thought that had fixed it; I'm looking at using the forced `resizeEvent` now to alleviate this issue. It's just not working as I expect. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @bpops I'm under the impression that you're having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why are you trying to access the size of the child widget during its initialization?

Comment: There's another trick you can use to print the size accurately: QTimer.singleShot() will run a function at a later time, and seems like it can give you results after everything is initialized. `from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer`. Then put your print stuff in a separate function (myfunction). Call singleShot like this `QTimer.singleShot(1000, myfunction)`